# Google Maps heatmap returning 404 on tiles when coordinates in array are the same

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I'm experiencing a weird error when using the Google Maps JS API 3.

I'm generating a heatmap based on an array of coordinates. At times and when filtering the results of the array, the resulting list consists of the same coordinate repeated several times in the array (X cases occurring in the same coordinates).

When this happens, the map will not render correctly and I'll get an array of 404 errors for the corresponding tiles, as shown below:

[image]

If then I touch the map zoom either up or down, it will render correctly.
This only happens if the coordinates are the same, if there's 2 different locations in the array, it will be rendered correctly.

Here's the code that renders my map:

```
$scope.renderHeatMap = function() {
  $timeout( function(){
    $scope.outbreakfin = [];
      for (var i in $scope.resultsheat) {
        $scope.outbreakfin.push(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.resultsheat[i][0], $scope.resultsheat[i][1]));
    };
    console.log($scope.outbreakfin);

    var map, heatmap;

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('heatmap'), {
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.outbreakfin.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend($scope.outbreakfin[i]);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    var options = {
      imagePath: 'images/m',
      gridSize:5
    };

    map.setCenter(center);

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: $scope.outbreakfin,
      map: map
    });

    heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 15);
    heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.7);
    heatmap.set('dissipating', heatmap.get('dissipating') ? null : true);
    heatmap.set('maxIntensity', heatmap.get('maxIntensity') ? null : 15);

  }, 0 );
};
```

Anyone has any idea about what I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for any future wanderers around this issue, I've figured it out.

The problem is around the `map.fitBounds(bounds);` call.
If all the coordinates are the same, the `fitBounds` will most likely try to display set a very high zoom level, which triggers the 404 errors.

To fix the issue, I've found a way to reset the zoom level *after* the `fitBounds` is set.

It looks like this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.outbreakfin.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend($scope.outbreakfin[i]);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);

var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
  if (map.getZoom() > 18) map.setZoom(18); 
  google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
});
```